# Nodejs clientCertEngine

Tags: node.js, openssl

Node.js Version: 11.2.0

OS: debian

Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?): issue with 'no client cert method' in tls handshake

Module (and version) (if relevant): openssl node tls clientCertEngine

Having issues with this trying to use a Hardware Security Module which stores the private key. (non readable/non exportable)

Without the HSM, there are no issues. Maybe I am calling clientCertEngine incorrectly? Or is there issue not allowing us to enter -keyform e?

although using s_client works as follows:

```
openssl s_client -host myHost.com -port 3000 -key fake.key -cert device.crt -CAfile ca.crt -engine hsm_engine -keyform e
```

When running client node tls connect:

```
_tls_common.js:204 c.context.setClientCertEngine(options.clientCertEngine);

Error: error:1412214B:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_engine:no client cert method
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:204:17)
    at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1205:48)
    at Object. (/home/pi/test/tls.js:20:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
```

And the js code

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const options = { // key: null //cannot be exported nor read. Ive tried with both null and removed key entirely
cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'),
clientCertEngine: '/path/to/hsm/.so file',
ca: [fs.readFileSync('ca.crt')], };
const socket =tls.connect({
    host: 'myHost.com',
    port: 3000 },
    options, () => { console.log('client connected', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
    process.stdin.pipe(socket);
    process.stdin.resume(); });
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', (data) => { console.log(data); }); socket.on('end', () => { console.log('server ends connection'); });
```

Comment: By the way, this does work with crypto.setEngine (engine_so, crypto.constants.ENGINE_MODE_ALL). Just not with tls @node/crypto

Comment: should it be hsm_engine instead of path as in openssl example. I think nodejs is just passing it to openssl